Kotlin's Any doesn't accept List
Could anyone explain me why I can't pass a list as a parameter to a function which accepts Any in Kotlin? I thought of an Any as an equivalent of Java's Object but seems like it's not. This code:
fun fu(obj: Any) {
    print(obj)
}

fun other() {
    fu(emptyList())
}

leads to a compilation error: "Not enough information to infer type variable T".
If I call it with a string or a number then it compiles, with listOf() or emptyList() -- doesn't.

The problem is not with the Any type, that will work as expected. The problem is that you cannot even create an emptyList() in the first place. That is because a List has a generic type parameter that determines which type of elements can be placed in the List. That could be anything you want, but you have to specify it when you create the List.
For example, you can use emptyList<String>() or emptyList<Int>(). You can even use emptyList<Any>().

And to close the link with Java: while Java allows raw types (where type parameters aren't specified) for historical reasons, Kotlin doesn't — every List must have a type.
